# Deleting row from an sql database

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to delete a row from my database and I am getting the following error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Also I have `"where ID = 1"`

Is it possible for me to have a getmethod to get the key(number) instead of having to type 1, 2 or 3 etc. a copy of the code is below

```
package prototype4;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DeleteSong extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private Connection con;
    private Statement stmt;
    private ResultSet res;
    JTextField songNo = new JTextField(7);
    TextArea information = new TextArea(2, 50);
    JButton delete = new JButton("Delete Song");
    JButton update = new JButton("Update Table");
    static String[] columnNames = {"trackNo", "Artist", "trackName"};
    static Object[][] data = null;
    static JTable table;
    static DefaultTableModel modeltable = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    Font timeFont = new Font("Gill Sans MT", Font.BOLD, 15);

    //object constructor which delcares the physical look of the frame including the title
    public DeleteSong() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 250); //set the size of the frame in pixels
        setTitle("Delete Song"); //set the title of the frame

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


        JPanel top = new JPanel(); 
        top.add(new JLabel("Enter Song Number:"));
        top.add(songNo);
        top.add(delete); 
        delete.addActionListener(this); 
        top.add(update);
        update.addActionListener(this);
        add("North", top); 

        JPanel middle = new JPanel(); line
        middle.add(information); 
        add("Center", middle);

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        table = new JTable(modeltable);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        panel2.add(scrollPane);
        add("West", panel2);

        setResizable(false); 
        setVisible(true);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        information.setFont(timeFont);
        information.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM LibraryTable");
            String key = songNo.getText(); //get the song number from the songNo text field 
            String name = LibraryData.getName(key); //get the name of the song from the LibraryData.java(another java class)
            //conditions
            if (name == null) {
                information.setText("No such song");
            } else {
                int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to delete " + key + " " + name.toUpperCase() + " ?");
                if (confirm == 0) {
                    LibraryData.remove(key);
                    stmt = con.createStatement();
                    String sql = "DELETE FROM LibraryTable "
                            + "WHERE ID = 1";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                    information.setText(key + "-" + name + " has been deleted and database updated!");
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DeleteSong.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at prototype4.DeleteSong.actionPerformed(DeleteSong.java:92)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
>   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="New Oracle"

Comment: The stack trace of the exception tells you exactly where it happens. Something is null at this line.

Comment: Could you post the entire stack trace? It will tell you where the exception is occurring.

Comment: You should initialise the connection 'con'. Also you should close connections and statements.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialized the `con` object variable. you need to do

```
con =  DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Please refer to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm) for more details.

Comment: thanks for that, i just tried it and it stil doesnt work, its saying that there's a problem from when it get to the stmt section in the bottom half of the code

Comment: Which is the line 92 ?

Comment: You have to set your own `URL`, don't just copy and past the above line. check the link above to create your own `URL`.

Comment: line 90 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       line 91 try {
         line 92   stmt = con.createStatement();

Comment: my university created the url, which is what i havce to use in order to connect to my area of the databse

Comment: Have you added the `con =  DriverManager.getConnection(url);` after the line 91  and it throws the same exception ?

Comment: could you please post what have you added?

Comment: Given the line number it must be that con is null

Comment: ok so it works now, the mistake i made was that when salah asked me to initialize the con = driver method i put it in the wrong place so i moved it to line 93 just under the stmt = con.create.... i tried it and now it works perfectly

Comment: You should close the connections, statements and resultSet.

Comment: `finally{ if(statement!=null; statement.close()} ` or  `try( statement = ... ) { }` if you use java 1.7